# LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost] and Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2, web.xml

Encountered this issue when I tried to deploy my project on tomcat. I've already checked that both compiled version and JVM of Tomcat version are the same...

Still, I can't figure out why this error happened...

The error msg from console:

> ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AddressBookBeta]]
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
>       at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:256)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationListenerAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:86)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:63)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:335)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:782)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:306)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5171)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
>       ... 10 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tiles.request.ApplicationContext
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1139)
>       ... 24 more
>
> org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
>   Error deploying configuration descriptor /Users/ChangGuoxuan/Desktop/TemporaryFiles/EclipseWorkspace/apache-tomcat-8.0.35/conf/Catalina/localhost/AddressBookBeta.xml
>       java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component
>   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/AddressBookBeta]]
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:587)
>         at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1798)
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

this is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
  <display-name>AddressBookBeta</display-name>

  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.DEFINITIONS_CONFIG</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
  </listener>

  <filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter
    </filter-class>
  </filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>/main/home.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

and this is struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.3//EN"
    "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.3.dtd">  
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false"/>
    <package name="menuDefault" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="*Menu" 
            class="com.prj.action.MenuAction" method="{1}Menu">
            <result name="home">home.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>

    <package name="userDefault" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles" 
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult"/>
        </result-types>
        <action name="loginUser" class="com.prj.action.UserAction" method="validateUser">
            <result name="success">home.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/main/login.jsp</result>
        </action>
        <action name="registerUser" class="com.prj.action.UserAction" method="registerUser">
            <result name="success">/main/register.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

I'm new on struts2, so any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you are using Apache Tiles but have forgotten to include all required libraries in the war file - `org/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext`.

Comment: @Boris the Spider thanks, but after i added the war file I missed. I got a new error says " Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener" / "java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.tiles.startup.AbstractTilesInitializer.createContainerFactory(Lorg/apache/tiles/request/ApplicationContext;)Lorg/apache/tiles/factory/AbstractTilesContainerFactory;" can you give me some solutions?

Comment: You are still missing libraries. Either 1) go **carefully** through the Tiles site, working out the exact versions of all required dependencies (note this may require you do work out the dependencies of the dependencies). Or 2) Use Maven (this is what most people do).

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Boris the Spider really appreciate that!